# Selecting a specific div element with Xpath and Nokogiri?

Tags: xpath, sinatra, nokogiri

I am relatively new to parsing and would like to get more practice. I want to parse the following URL: http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/tag/hard-work.

I want to grab all quotes tagged "hard-work". This is what the site code breaks down to:

```
<div class="content">
<div id="siteheader" class="uitext">
<div class="mainContentContainer ">
<div class="mainContent">
<div id="premiumAdTop">
<div class="mainContentFloat">
<div id="flashContainer"> </div>
<div id="connectPrompt" style="">
<img style="float: left; margin: -3px 5px 0px 0px" src="http://s.gr-assets.com/assets/quote/quote_tiny-566b7de5e1ac5becd0dd8b2856f59228.jpg" alt="quote">
<h1>Quotes About Hard Work</h1>
<div class="leftContainer">
<div class="mediumText">
<div class="quote mediumText ">
<div class="quoteDetails ">
<a class="leftAlignedImage" href="/author/show/3916262.Babe_Ruth">
<div class="quoteText">
“It's hard to beat a person who never gives up.”
<br>
―
<a href="/author/show/3916262.Babe_Ruth">Babe Ruth</a>
</div>
```

Right now my code is:

```
require "rubygems"
require "open-uri"
require "nokogiri" 

@page = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://goodreads.com/quotes"))
@div = @page.xpath("html/body/div[1]")
```

But the results aren't giving me the output that I want.

I think I ought to call the methods `each` and `collect` but I just don't know how to get to the node that I want, which I believe is contained somewhere in here:

```
<div id="connectPrompt" style="">
<img style="float: left; margin: -3px 5px 0px 0px" src="http://s.gr-assets.com/assets/quote/quote_tiny-566b7de5e1ac5becd0dd8b2856f59228.jpg" alt="quote">
<h1>Quotes About Hard Work</h1>
<div class="leftContainer">
<div class="mediumText">
<div class="quote mediumText ">
<div class="quoteDetails ">
<a class="leftAlignedImage" href="/author/show/3916262.Babe_Ruth">
<div class="quoteText">
“It's hard to beat a person who never gives up.”
<br>
―
<a href="/author/show/3916262.Babe_Ruth">Babe Ruth</a>
</div>
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?  How far in do I have to go into the div class to get what I want?

Comment: You say you want to parse `http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/tag/hard-work` but your code fetches `http://www.goodreads.com/quotes`, so which is it? Also, you don’t specify what you want to extract from the page – just the quote text, the immediate `div` around it, the quote and the author, one of the other containing `div`s, something else. You need to be more specific.

Comment: Hi Matt! I want to extract all quotes tagged "hard-work" on the site www.good.reads.com. It appears to me that the only way to get that is by parsing the http://goodreads.com/quotes. 

I want the quote and the name of the author. Hope that helps. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the XPath:

```
//div[@class = 'quoteText' and following-sibling::div[1][@class = 'quoteFooter' and .//a[@href and normalize-space() =  'hard-work']]]
```

to select all the `div` elements whose class is `quoteText` and which are followed by a `div` with class `quoteFooter` containing a link with `hard-work`.

Comment: Hi Martin Honnen! Your feedback helped a lot; thank you. Didn't get all quotes tagged "hard-work" but got quotes tagged "hard-work" on the first page (there are 5 pages). 

Currently working with the code you provided above, hoping to manipulate it to give me what I need. Once again, thanks helping out. 

PS: any advise on resources? Want to practice a lot & need to get very comfortable with html/css to become decent at parsing. Will put in the time & work required & would appreciate tips on good stright-to-the-point resources for newbies. Thanks man!